# UIButton image not properly set when handled with tags

Tags: ios, uitableview, tags, uibutton, uiimage

In the prototype cell as no IBOutlet can be given so I got a handle on my UIbutton with a tag. But when setting the image for the button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method its not showing the correct image for enable and disabled state.

in cellForRowIndexPath:

```
if([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:CELL_ID_COMPLIANCE])
    _infoButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:800];
else
    _infoButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:900];

if([[comments objectAtIndex:kEntitlementComment] length] > 0){
    _infoButton.enabled= YES;
    [_infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_info.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    TRACELOG(@"the coments :%@", [comments objectAtIndex:kEntitlementComment]);
    }
else{
    _infoButton.enabled= NO;
    [_infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info_icon_disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }
```

I have two kind of prototype cells in the table but the button images are only of two kinds. I also tried

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doButtonSettings:)
```

with

```
Object:textArray waitUntilDone:YES];
```

in the selector I am setting the images for the button. As you know the buttonType is a private setter so cant be changed dynamically. How do i make button images consistent with the conditions?

Comment: Why don't you directly set the image of the button in the xib or storyboard. You say you have the 2 prototype cells.

Comment: I think your doing tableviews wrong..

Comment: the 2 prototype cells have different  columns and will be used under different users having different privileges. The button will look enable only when there is data. Anyways i had posted the fix down below. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the same tag for the buttons?

```
//All prototype cells info buttons have the same tag
_infoButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:900];

if([[comments objectAtIndex:kEntitlementComment] length] > 0){
    _infoButton.enabled= YES;
    [_infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_info.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    TRACELOG(@"the coments :%@", [comments objectAtIndex:kEntitlementComment]);
    }
else{
    _infoButton.enabled= NO;
    [_infoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info_icon_disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the calls to setImage to where the cell is created.  Set the images for both the normal AND disabled states for ALL buttons.

The in your if statement you only need to toggle the buttons state

```
if([[comments objectAtIndex:kEntitlementComment] length] > 0){
  _infoButton.enabled= YES;
}
else{
  _infoButton.enabled= NO;
}
```

But this change alone should not fix your issue.  It would be helpful if you would post all the code within cellForRowIndexPath.  I suspect that the issue is above where you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and then if nil create the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I got the soln:
Actually in the IBAction method i had popover tied to my infoButton.
- (IBAction)infoButtonAction:(id)sender event:(id) event {

```
NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:_summaryTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_summaryTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
UITableViewCell *cell  = [_summaryTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

_infoButton.tag=indexPath.row;

if ( [self.myPopoverController isPopoverVisible] )
{
    // Close the popover view if toolbar button was touched again and popover is already visible
    [self.myPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated: YES];
    return;
}

UIStoryboard                     *storyboard     = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: @"iPad" bundle: nil];
NSITSLMEntitlementSummCommentsViewController    *popoverContent = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"slm_ES_Comments"];

self.myPopoverController =   [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: popoverContent];
popoverContent.comments.text  = [[self.dataController getSummaryRecordAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:kEntitlementComment];

 // Present the popover view non-modally with a refrence to the toolbar button which was pressed
if([popoverContent.comments.text length] > 0)
    [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:cell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
_infoButton.tag= 800;
```

}

The info button tag was changing whenever i was pressing any of the buttons in the table. So i added the last line and now its fine. Thanx anyways..